# Spring Integration support for Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring-integration, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to use Spring Integration to write information to Amazon  DynamoDB?

Any sample code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Spring Integration Extension for AWS](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws) but DynamoDB is not yet supported.

Contributions are welcome.

It is, of course, easy enough to wrap any non-supported APIs in POJOs and invoke them using a service activator.

[Spring Cloud AWS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/) has some hooks for integrating with RDS over JDBC.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I will take a look.